# Why won't IE8 won't open ".XLS" file from server?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have code that is supposed to open a ".xls" (or ".doc") file that is hosted on the web server. In Firefox I get the prompt and it opens the file fine. However, in IE8 I get the yellow information bar. When I right-click the bar and select download file the page refreshes but the file doesn't open.

What setting do I need to uncheck/alter to allow the users to download and open this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unaware of an option you can uncheck. But there might be a registry key that can help you:

Begin in:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE - to change settings for all users
HKEY_CURRENT_USER- to change settings for the current user

Then browse to
Software->Microsoft->Internet Explorer->Main->FeatureControl->Feature_Restrict_File_Download

And then set the Value iexplore.exe to 0. If it doesn't exist: Create it (DWORD).

You might also want to take a look at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565669%28VS.85%29.aspx

I hope that helps...

Comment: thank you for the link.  That actually solved my issue.  I had to change one of the options in the security setting.