# IE7/8 won't open .XLS or .DOC file from server - Only for few users

Tags: security, internet-explorer, .doc

We have a lot of Excel, Word and PDF files on our intranet site for all the employees to download. For some users who have Windows XP Prof and IE 8, they can't open .doc or .xls  file types but they are able to open PDF files. It works fine in Chrome. When the file download - security warning pops up, they are not able to open or save. If I try to open, it's blank and if I try to save, I get an error. Also, the file extension is not .doc, it shows as _doc (see image). I read the below post but still it keeps doing the same thing.

[Why won't IE8 won't open ".XLS" file from server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723520/why-wont-ie8-wont-open-xls-file-from-server?rq=1)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding the intranet servers to the list of trusted web sites? Otherwise you could try setting .doc and so on as low risk file types via GPO http://www.ehow.com/how_5804009_disable-security-warning-windows-xp.html

Comment: Yes, the intranet site is already added to the trusted zone.

Comment: GPO needs to be set on the Server or user machine?

Comment: What does the filename look like when downloading from external websites? Is it still _doc oder .doc then?